# Typescript negated void: enforce function to return not void

Tags: typescript

How can I make sure a function returns *something* in typescript?

Since `void` is a subtype of `any`, none of the generics to exclude `void` from `any` seem to work.

My current workaround is:

```
type NotVoid = { [key: string]: NotVoid } | object | string | boolean | symbol | number | null | undefined
```

The above seems rather verbose. I hope there's a better way!

I'm aware that there is a proposal for negation, but I'd like to achieve this today & it must be typescript, not a linting rule. Thanks!

Comment: Why include `undefined` in `NotVoid`?

Comment: i'm not opposed to removing it, but the primary goal is to force a return statement

Comment: If there is no return statement, JavaScript functions will return `undefined`

Comment: correct. i want to force a return statement.

Comment: Ah, so that `() => { return; }` is valid but `() => {}` isn't?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
type NotVoid<T extends Function> = (() => void) extends T ? never : T;
const f = <T extends Function>(func: NotVoid<T>) => func(); 

f(() => 0)  // ok
f(() => {}) // Error: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Unfortunately, this will also generate errors for cases of `f(() => undefined)` and `f(() => null)`.

Comment: `T extends Function` may annoy [`@typescript-eslint/ban-types`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/): https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4390